# Windows Phone 8 ChannelUriUpdated not fired

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I encountered a problem while developing the Windows Phone push notification. The  `ChannelUriUpdated` event wasn't triggered at all. When I register the `ConnectionStatusChanged` event as follow:

```
  void pushChannel_ConnectionStatusChanged(object sender, NotificationChannelConnectionEventArgs e)
    {
        var state = e.ConnectionStatus;
    }
```

And the `ConnectionStatusChanged` is continuously triggered. The "state" value is alternately Connected and Disconnected.

I use the Code : [MSDN Push Notification Sample Code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Toast-Notification-Sample-fb20ae13)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follw below link

[How to send and receive toast notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202967%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Push Notification for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Use below code its work for me

```
 HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

            // The name of our push channel.
            string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

            InitializeComponent();

            // Try to find the push channel.
            pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

            // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
            if (pushChannel == null)
            {
                pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

                // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                pushChannel.Open();

                // Bind this new channel for toast events.
                pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

            }
            else
            {
                // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                    pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

            }
        }
```

hope it will work for you...if any query than comment here....

Comment: The code you posted is the same with MSDN Push Notification Sample Code which I used.